# python-3.6 printing set expression not in order

Tags: python, set, python-3.6

There is one question about `Python3.6`. It's about the output of Set expressions. I do not know why the code below does not appear in order:

```
a = {i*2 for i in range(1, 5)}
print(a)
```

I expect `{2, 4, 6, 8}` but the output is `{8, 2, 4, 6}`

Why it is not in order?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the documentation; the first sentence of the [`set` documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) is:

> A set object is an **unordered** collection of distinct hashable objects.

So the order of the elements in the set is for all practical purposes **random**. Even in python-3.6.

Answer (score 0):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZuZ2.jpg)here is the example in python, elements of the set doesn't arrange in order i.e elements are arrange in random

Answer (score 0):

Python sets are not ordered, they only contain elements. If you need your data structure to have a certain order, maybe consider an OrderedDict.